# example_parser_configuration_pb2 import issue for tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

Using Python 2.7 (miniconda) and trying to run below example, but it is said Unresolved reference to `example_parser_configuration_pb2`, does anyone have any solutions?

BTW, my machine is configured with tensorflow and I can run some tensorflow examples, so tensorflow basic configuration should be ok.

```
from tensorflow.core.example import example_parser_configuration_pb2
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/python/util/example_parser_configuration_test.py#L70

[image]

[image]

regards,
Lin

Comment: Could you paste the full error message and stack trace?

Comment: @Fake, for sure, post the error message. Actually I have not run yet, Pycharm report error dues to unresolved reference. If you have any ideas, it will be great. My current thought is, maybe I need to compile a protobuf file to generate example_parser_configuration_pb2? I have not found a detailed step yet.

Comment: You don't have to compile the protobuf. Are you using the correct protobuf version? (>=3.0)

Comment: @Fake, how to check quickly? I am pretty sure I have protobuf installed, but not sure about version.

Comment: In your terminal, run `pip freeze | grep protobuf`.

Comment: @Fake, thanks and since I am using `miniconda` as python interpreter, I think I should not use `pip` to check. I just verified in Pycharm and I am using protobuf 3.0 already. See updated screen snapshot. If you have any further ideas, or have some command to double check the `protobuf` version with `miniconda` other than `pip`, I am happy to have a try.